# How to to add radioButtons into tableviewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios4

How do I add radioButtons into tableviewCell in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this sample [tutorial](http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/02/radio-button-behavior-for-table-rows.html).

[Tutorial 2](http://walkingsmarts.com/creating-radio-button-and-checkbox-lists-using-uitableview/)

[Tutorial 3](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

add custom buttons to table view cell and add those button , an image which looks like radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

Try use standart controls. There is no radio button in `UIKit` framework, but we have `UISegmentedControl` with similar functionality in it.
[Read documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) about this control